# How to produce a value on that hash corresponding to the key, or nil by default

Tags: ruby

I ran into a bit of an road block on a beginner exercise for hashes in Ruby. I have the following problem to solve:

> Create a method call read_from_hash that takes in two parameters. The first parameter is a hash, the second is a key. Used together, they will either produce a value on that hash corresponding to the key, or nil by default. Use these two parameters in conjunction to do just that.

Here's my code:

```
def read_from_hash(hash, key)
  hash = {key => "value"}
  hash(key)
end
```

Here's the error:

```
     Failure/Error: expect(read_from_hash({name: 'Steve'}, :name)).to eq('Steve')

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

Comment: Hash access uses `[]`, not `()`, which attempts to call a method.

Comment: In addition to @DaveNewton's comment: the method `hash(...)` is attempting to invoke is [`Kernel#hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-hash) – a method available to all objects. That method doesn't take an argument, hence the `ArgumentError`.

Comment: Please read "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)".

Answer (score 2):

What you want is simply:

```
def read_from_hash(hash, key)
  hash[key]
end
h = {a: 1, b: 2}

read_from_hash(h, :a)
#=> 1
read_from_hash(h, :c)
#=> nil
```

Or for your example:

```
read_from_hash({name: 'Steve'}, :name)
#=> 'Steve'
```

Your current code:

```
hash = {key => "value"}
```

creates a new `hash` variable, overwriting the one that's being passed in through the params, while here:

```
hash(key)
```

you're trying to access the value of the element with the key `key` using regular parentheses  `()` instead of brackets `[]`. Because of that, what is is actually happening is that you're calling a `#hash` method and passing it the `key` variable as a parameter.

Comment: _"`hash(key)` # tries to access the value of the element ..."_ – I think it would be cleaner to say it tries to call a method named `hash`. Ruby doesn't know what you _intended_ to do.

Comment: @Stefan Edited, I hope it's clearer now. Thanks for the suggestion